# Automatic download of dynamically generated pdf sheets using PHP and FPDF

Tags: php, http, pdf, download, fpdf

So my problem is as follows.
I have a bunch of articles and every article has a specification sheet.

These sheets are in pdf format and dynamically generated using PHP and the FPDF class.
For convenience i would like to automatically generate all articles' (about 200) specification sheets and download them all to a specific file directory.

I tried a solution using PHPs file_get_contents which won't work because the pdf file does not seem to be generated at time of the function call.

I haven't found any suitable solution to this problem so far.

Comment: Your question is vague, it is unclear what you ask. You claim you tried something, but you do not provide your code. We cannot help with this, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save files to a folder

```
require('fpdf.php');

//create a FPDF object
$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->Output($dir.$filename,'F');
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339787/saving-file-into-a-prespecified-directory-using-fpdf) may help you.